# ~/.rpmmacros and how to view/add to it

Tags: linux, centos, java, rpm

I am currently following a [guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS#head-208acde722d39981a92b376999b284793a0b198b) to install Java 1.4 on the CentOS site and was wondering if anyone could help me understand some of the terminology.

It states:

> For this example, it will be assumed that the contents of ~/.rpmmacros
> includes:
>
> %_topdir /home//rpmbuild
>
> %_tmppath %{_topdir}/tmp
>
> Remember to create the ~/rpmbuild/ tree if it has not been created
> yet, but be aware that your directory is not required to be named
> "rpmbuild" as in this example (consult your ~/.rpmmacros to know):

Where would `~/.rpmmacros` be located and how would I ensure it contained the two lines beginning `%`?

Additionally how would I create the ~/.rpmbuild/ tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where would ~/.rpmmacros be located...

In most Unix shells, `~` is an abbreviation for "your home directory".  So `~/.rpmmacros` is the file `.rpmmacros` in your home directory.  The contents you have listed...

```
%_topdir /home//rpmbuild
%_tmppath %{_topdir}/tmp
```

...are problematic; that first line is meant to be the path to your home directory and should include your username.  For example:

```
%_topdir /home/gharping/rpmbuild
```

> ...and how would I ensure it contained the two lines beginning %?

You would use your favorite text editor...like `vim` or `emacs` or `gedit` or something similar.

> Additionally how would I create the ~/.rpmbuild/ tree?

You use the `mkdir` command to create directories.  From within your home directory, you could run:

```
mkdir -p rpmbuild/tmp
```

...to create both the `rpmbuild` and `rpmbuild/tmp/` directories.

Answer (score -4):

In my case(CentOS 6.4), I found the list of all macros inside `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`, just edit the file...